# Django Static txt file not loading

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

This is my template file in blog app

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world! Blog</h1>
        <a href="{% static 'blog/mystatic.txt'%}">Click Me</a>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is a static file in blog app 'mystatic.txt', which I am trying to load using anchor tag in above code, which is giving me error.

[image: Directory structure of blog app]

[image: Error]

I want to know why this is happening and what can I do to resolve it.

Comment: Try clearing browser cache for 127.0.0.1, restart server, and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use static syntax for URLs in your urls.py file?

i am talking about this code :

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and at before putting this code to your URLs.py file add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py file.

Comment: Yes, I will try this, and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following code in `settings.py`.

```
#settings.py
.....
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # this
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
....
```

Then move `*.html` to `project/templates`.

> Note: Not move to `app/templates`

You don’t need to change static folder.

Comment: Please provide the function in views.py that calls this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the error code, `'blog\mystatic.html'` not found. But in your blog folder you've created a `'mystatic.txt'` file, you can change that to `mystatic.html`